# customised label value number and number with alphacharacters

Tags: cross-referencing, affiliation

I would like to print the affiliation `number only` and `number with alphabetic characters`. Please find MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{subaff}
\setcounter{subaff}{0}
\renewcommand\thesubaff{\@alph\c@subaff}
\newcommand{\subaff}[1]{\addtocounter{Label}{0}#1}
\newcounter{Label}
\setcounter{Label}{0}
\def\Affiliation#1{\refstepcounter{Label}
\gdef\@Affiliation{%
\def\iand{\refstepcounter{Label}\ignorespaces\item[\hfill${}^{\theLabel}$\ignorespaces]\label{aff\theLabel}\ignorespaces}%
\def\tempand{\refstepcounter{Label}\refstepcounter{subaff}\ignorespaces\item[\hfill${}^{\theLabel\thesubaff}$\ignorespaces]\label{aff\theLabel}\addtocounter{Label}{-1}\ignorespaces}%
\let\and=\iand%
\let\suband=\tempand
\topsep.7mm\trivlist\item[\hfill${}^{\theLabel}$\ignorespaces]\item[]\hskip-6pt\label{aff\theLabel}#1\endtrivlist}}
%%%Make Title
\def\@maketitle{%
\newpage
\null
\begin{center}%
\let \footnote \thanks
{\LARGE \@title \par}%
\vskip 1.5em%
{\large
\lineskip .5em%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
\@author
\end{tabular}\par}%
{\@Affiliation}
\end{center}%
\par
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\title{Cross-Links check}
\author{A. Aab\ref{1}\and P. Abreu\ref{4}\and M. Aglietta\ref{6}\and E. J. Ahn\ref{2}}

\Affiliation{
1st Affiliation without alphabetic-characters like $^1$, Rome, Italy
\and
2th Affiliation without alphabetic-characters like $^2$, Rome, Italy
\subaff{
\suband{
3rd Affiliation with alphabetic-characters like ${}^{3{\rm a}}$, Rome, Italy}
\suband{
3rd Affiliation with alphabetic-characters like ${}^{3{\rm b}}$, Rome, Italy}
}
\and
4th Affiliation without alphabetic-characters like $^4$, Rome, Italy
\and
5th Affiliation without alphabetic-characters like $^5$, Rome, Italy}
\maketitle
How do get the affiliations labels in author references??? If \verb|\ref{4}| should be display \verb|^{3b}| like that...
\end{document}
```

How do get the affiliations labels in author references??? If `\ref{4}` should be display `^{3b}` like that... How do achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to set the affiliations in the footer, you can hijack footnotes using the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\affiliation}[1]{{%
  \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{#1}%
  \footnotemark[0]}}
\newcommand{\affiliationtext}[2]{{%
  \renewcommand{\thempfn}{#1}%
  \footnotetext[0]{#2}}}
\makeatother

\title{My title}
\author{A~Author\affiliation{1} \and
        B~Author\affiliation{2a} \and 
        C~Author\affiliation{2b} \and 
        D~Author\affiliation{3}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\affiliationtext{1}{First affiliation}
\affiliationtext{2a}{Second sub-affiliation}
\affiliationtext{2b}{Second sub-affiliation}
\affiliationtext{3}{Third affiliation}

\end{document}
```

---

You could also use references:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\affiliation}[1]{{%
  \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\ref{#1}}%
  \footnotemark[0]}}
\newcommand{\affiliationtext}[3]{{%
  \renewcommand{\@currentlabel}{#2}\label{#1}%
  \renewcommand{\thempfn}{#2}%
  \footnotetext[0]{#3}}}
\makeatother

\title{My title}
\author{A~Author\affiliation{first} \and
        B~Author\affiliation{second} \and 
        C~Author\affiliation{third} \and 
        D~Author\affiliation{fourth}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\affiliationtext{first}{1}{First affiliation}
\affiliationtext{second}{2a}{Second sub-affiliation}
\affiliationtext{third}{2b}{Second sub-affiliation}
\affiliationtext{fourth}{3}{Third affiliation}

\end{document}
```

The use of a three-parameter `\affiliationtext{<label>}{<ref>}{<text>}` helps provide context in terms of the code.

Comment: Werner: I would not like to hardcode text like `\affiliation{2b}` and would like `\ref{cite2}` and \ref{cite3} etc.. If `\ref{cite2}` need to print `2a`, if `\ref{cite3}` need to print `2b`.

Comment: @Balaji: I've added some update. Give feedback on the interface.

Comment: This is OK. But I have `n number` of author in my document. How to do automatically increase the counter instead of `first`, `second`, `third` etc (include `\ref`and `\label`)...

Comment: @Balaji: By `n` I assume you mean "many". While the process of automation might be possible, you seem to require intermixing of "sub-affiliations", which requires a way of controlling the "author stepping" in some way. I'm tempted to say that for such a one-off usage, there seems very little benefit in automation.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain a little more what you want in the user-interface.

Comment: @Wernet: If author `affiliationtext` count is `10`, but `affiliation` containing `5a, 5b, 5c, 5d`. So that the `affiliation` counter now is `13`. If i have use `\affiliation{7}` the `\affiliation` text value should be print `5c`. I hope now you got clear idea...